# How long can the stop in a stop-and-go be?

Tags: faa-regulations, landing

When a pilot is cleared for a stop and go, how long does this allow them to be stopped on the runway?

I'd like to know if there is a limit in regulations or at least guidance for this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[The AIM covers this briefly](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/AIM_Basic_dtd_10-12-17.pdf) (bolded the important part) but effectively you cant sit there very long:

> **4−3−22. Option Approach**
>
> The “Cleared for the Option” procedure will permit an instructor,
>   flight examiner or pilot the option to make a touch−and−go, low
>   approach, missed approach, **stop−and−go**, or full stop landing. This
>   procedure can be very beneficial in a training situation in that
>   neither the student pilot nor examinee would know what maneuver would
>   be accomplished. The pilot should make a request for this procedure
>   passing the final approach fix inbound on an instrument approach or
>   entering downwind for a VFR traffic pattern. **After ATC approval of
>   the option, the pilot should inform ATC as soon as possible of any
>   delay on the runway during their stop-and-go or full stop landing.**
>   The advantages of this procedure as a training aid are that it enables
>   an instructor or examiner to obtain the reaction of a trainee or
>   examinee under changing conditions, the pilot would not have to
>   discontinue an approach in the middle of the procedure due to student
>   error or pilot proficiency requirements, and finally it allows more
>   flexibility and economy in training programs. This procedure will only
>   be used at those locations with an operational control tower and will
>   be subject to ATC approval.

The way I read that is effectively you come to a stop and get going as soon as possible. If you intend on doing anything else you should inform ATC. I take this to be a time limit of, as soon as you stop, get going again.